# random variable to continuous function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity, random-variables

Show that for any random variable $X$, the function $t\rightarrow \mathbf E[e^{-|t-X|}]$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

I am not getting any idea of how to approach it. Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know any properties of continuous functions? Definition of continuous functions?

Comment: For example, the simplest (in concept, but not always in practice) is to show it by definition. Did you examine how large $|E(e^{-|t-X|}) -E(e^{-|s-X|})|$ can be when $t$ is near $s$? Did this fail?

Comment: Yes. A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ will be continuous if for any open set $V$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in X

Comment: i think it will fail by definition of $E[f(X)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) d\mu_X$

Comment: it will? And Why is that? Im not convinced by your citation of what's usually called the "law of the unconscious statistician". I would slow down and think about this more carefully (and digest the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $t_n \to t$. Then an application of Lebesgue dominated convergence yields $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E(e^{-|t_n - X|}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega e^{-|t_n - X|} dP = \int_\Omega e^{-|t - X|} dP = E(e^{-|t - X|})$$ since $$|e^{-|t_n - X|}| \leq 1$$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: thanks for the help